# Why Inserting a new word in WordRoomDatabase codelab refresh all the list?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-listadapter

I don't get why the entire list is refresh (and jump to the top) instead of only the new added word.
It's negating the purpose of SubmitList().

I tried to change the repository to manage a local *LiveData<List< Word>> getAllWords* without room and it worked well.

Is there something in room that cause the *LiveData<List< Word>> getAllWords* to completely refresh ? If so how to avoid it, It's ugly.

**WORD REPOSITORY**

> ```
>    class WordRepository {
>     
>         private WordDao mWordDao;
>         private LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;
>     
>         WordRepository(Application application) {
>             WordRoomDatabase db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
>             mWordDao = db.wordDao();
>             mAllWords = mWordDao.getAlphabetizedWords();
>         }
>     
>         LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords() {
>             return mAllWords;
>         }
>     
>         void insert(Word word) {
>             WordRoomDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
>                 mWordDao.insert(word);
>             });
>         }
>     }
> ```

**WORD VIEWMODEL**

> ```
> public class WordViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
>
>     private WordRepository mRepository;
>     private final LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;
>
>     public WordViewModel(Application application) {
>         super(application);
>         mRepository = new WordRepository(application);
>         mAllWords = mRepository.getAllWords();
>     }
>
>     LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords() {
>         return mAllWords;
>     }
>
>     void insert(Word word) {
>         mRepository.insert(word);
>     }
> }
> ```

**WORD DAO**

> ```
> public interface WordDao {
>
>     @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
>     LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords();
>
>     @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
>     void insert(Word word);
>
>     @Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
>     void deleteAll();
> }
> ```

**WORD ADAPTER**

> ```
> public class WordListAdapter extends ListAdapter<Word, WordViewHolder> {
>
>     public WordListAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Word> diffCallback) {
>         super(diffCallback);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public WordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
>         return WordViewHolder.create(parent);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onBindViewHolder(WordViewHolder holder, int position) {
>         Word current = getItem(position);
>         holder.bind(current.getWord());
>     }
>
>     static class WordDiff extends DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Word> {
>
>         @Override
>         public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Word oldItem, @NonNull Word newItem) {
>             return oldItem == newItem;
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Word oldItem, @NonNull Word newItem) {
>             return oldItem.getWord().equals(newItem.getWord());
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
>     public static final int NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
>
>     private WordViewModel mWordViewModel;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>         RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
>         final WordListAdapter adapter = new WordListAdapter(new WordListAdapter.WordDiff());
>         recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
>         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
>
>         mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class);
>
>         mWordViewModel.getAllWords().observe(this, new Observer<List<Word>>() {
>             @Override
>             public void onChanged(List<Word> list) {
>                 adapter.submitList(list);
>             }
>         });
>
>         FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
>         fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View view) {
>                 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewWordActivity.class);
>                 MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
>             }
>         });
>     }
>
>     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
>
>         if (requestCode == NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
>             Word word = new Word(data.getStringExtra(NewWordActivity.EXTRA_REPLY));
>             mWordViewModel.insert(word);
>         } else {
>             Toast.makeText(
>                     getApplicationContext(),
>                     R.string.empty_not_saved,
>                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Adding an element will invalidate queries which touch the database tables it relates to, all that happens is these queries are re-run, producing a new list in this case - this is by design. `ListAdapter::submistList` should perform an async computation on the new list and work out what has changed.  This will be predicated on your `DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Work>` implementation - if everytime you add an item the result is to invalidate the entire recyclerview list then there is a problem with the item callback see : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check generated by Room library code

```
@Override
public LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords() {
    // ...
    return new ComputableLiveData<List<Word>>() {
        private Observer _observer;

        @Override
        protected List<Word> compute() {
            if (_observer == null) {
                _observer = new Observer("word_table") {
                    @Override
                    public void onInvalidated(@NonNull Set<String> tables) {
                        invalidate();
                    }
                };
                __db.getInvalidationTracker().addWeakObserver(_observer);
            }
            final Cursor cursor = __db.query(_statement);
            final List<Word> _result = new ArrayList<Word>(cursor.getCount());
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                final Word item = createNewWordInstanceFromCursorData(cursor);
                _result.add(item);
            }
            // ...
        }
    }.getLiveData();
}
```

After the first execution of the `getAlphabetizedWords()` method, the new table invalidation observer will be added. This `Observer` will be triggered after each transaction in a database table, such as inserting a new word or deleting one. So, after this, `invalidate()` method of `ComputableLiveData` will be called, which leads to the recomputation of the entire list of the words. `LiveData` value will be set to an entirely new instance of `List` with new instances of `Word` items.

In `WordDiff` class `areItemsTheSame()` method is implemented to check object references. But in this case, we will get new `Word` instances and this implementation will return false. This leads to a full refresh of the list. In this case, you might change the implementation to the following

```
static class WordDiff extends DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Word> {

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Word oldItem, @NonNull Word newItem) {
        return oldItem.getWord().equals(newItem.getWord());
    }

    // ...
}
```

In more complex cases, you might check the unique data per elements, such as item id. See more: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil.ItemCallback#areItemsTheSame(T,T)